# ionic2 left side menu background color changing after clicked

Tags: ionic-framework

How to change left menu item's background color after clicked on left side menu in ionic 2 .
I have attached 2 images. when I clicked notifications menu I want to change its background color like image 2.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngClass`

### app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [ngClass]="{'selectedMenu' : (p.title == selectedmenu)}">
                {{p.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp 
{
    rootPage:any = HomePage;
    pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
    selectedmenu: String;
    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) 
    {
        this.pages = [
        { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
        { title: 'Contact', component: HomePage },
        { title: 'About', component: HomePage },
        { title: 'Notification', component: HomePage },
        ];

        platform.ready().then(() => 
        {
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }

    openPage(obj)
    {
        this.selectedmenu = obj.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your immediate response.

Comment: Glad if that will work for you. Please dont forgot to upvote and accept answer

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I applied your answer to my code. Actually it applies class for button. but the css I have put which not apply and not load to css  file when debug. I have attached my css and debug output. [enter image description here][1]


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW3So.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwn3.png

Comment: I am using this simple class for highlight clicked menu .selectedMenu
{
 background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}

Comment: This css styles not working. but class has applied. This css need to put app.scss , right?

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my time. It works properly